# How to increment Dates and use them with operators like '>' or '<' in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I increment date in `WHILE LOOP` in a loop like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime = some_date;
DECLARE @EndDate Datetime = other_date;
DECLARE @FinishDate Datetime = last_date;
    WHILE @EndDate < @FinishDate
      BEGIN
         [something happens]
        SET @StartDate = [ plus 1 day to @EndDate ]
        SET @EndDate = [ plus 8 days to itself]
      END
```

And can I use an operator `<` in an expression lik this `@EndDate < @FinishDate` ?
By the way, I've tried to use `DATEADD` but it doesn't work. If i set data-type `DATETIME2` it returns with `ERROR 8117`.

Comment: "but it doesn't work." is not a problem description. Why didn't `dateadd` work?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work": specify any errors you get

Comment: That error number probably also has a message - please add to your question

Comment: The better question here is, why use a cursor? There are (probably) much better dataset based ways of doing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Larnu Tryin to get some data within each week (7 days).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Well, i've already told about mistake (answer from @Leran2002)

Comment: @HansKesting Error message is like `you cannot use datetime2 data type in an operand add`. And about "why does it not work" - the dates were written in the wrong way. Now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it must work if you use SQLServer

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@EndDate)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,8,@EndDate)
```

Test

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime = '20171201';
DECLARE @EndDate Datetime = '20171205';
DECLARE @FinishDate Datetime = '20171231';
    WHILE @EndDate < @FinishDate
      BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@EndDate)
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,8,@EndDate)

        PRINT CONVERT(varchar(10),@StartDate,120)+' - '+CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,120)
      END
```

Comment: Try to use the test in my answer. Check date values in your script.

Comment: Thanks. I found my mistake. In your test dates are like `20171201` but I used `01.12.2017` because I have them in a table written in that way. Now i should figure out how to convert it to your style when I `SELECT` dates from table and sets them as variables.

Comment: I think you can use `CONVERT(date,'01.12.2017',104)`. Style 104 is `dd.mm.yyyy`.  See all the styles here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov so your basic problem is that you use varchar columns to store date values. Please try and use the correct data type.

Comment: @HansKesting they are not varchar, i just have another default language. The have `DATE` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment the OP made above, they are looking for weeks up to the finish date. Rather than doing this with a loop, it can much more easily (and efficiently) be achieved with a rCTE:

```
DECLARE @FinishDate datetime = '20171231', @StartDate datetime = '20171204';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @StartDate);

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate,
           @EndDate AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7,StartDate),
           DATEADD(DAY, 7,EndDate)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 7,EndDate) <= @FinishDate)
SELECT *
FROM Dates;
```

This gives you all the weeks in December 2017.

Comment: Can it be used for a period of 5-6 years? Asking because i've tried and it returns wtih `ERROR 530: maximum of recursion 100 was used before instruction end`. And it gives only 100 weeks.

Comment: Got it - used `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)`

Comment: Yes, as you've already worked out. :) rCTE's, by default, only have a max recursion of 100 (so you don't overload your server), however, you can up the max using `OPTION`.

Comment: But how can i use those weeks? I mean can i use all that script as a table? Or can i add to it any needed columns with different data, for example monye sum?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. You can `JOIN` that dataset just like any other dataset. `Dates` is effectively a Table, albeit derived from an expression. So you could then (in the same query) do something like: `SELECT * FROM Dates D JOIN MyTable MT ON D.StartDate <= MT.DateValue AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate) > D.DateValue;`

Comment: Ok, i understood. Thanks